# Convert java.util.Date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format to compatible with MySQL DATETIME

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

For log entry of a web application I have table with primary key `DATETIME` in MySQL table.
But `java.util.Date` is in different format causing mapping error in Hibernate.

How can I map `DATETIME` type of MySQL table to `java.util.Date`?

Comment: have you tried something like `TO_DATE(yourdate)` in your sql?

Comment: The "format" of the date is *irrelevant* unless you're pooping it out in text somewhere. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389084/hibernate-mapping-mysql-datetime for general ideas of how to resolve this.

Comment: No, and I am actually using Hibernate to store data in MySQL tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
java.sql.Timestamp oracleDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(yourdate.getTime());
```

edit...

I just checked what I was doing in some of my code, and java.util.Date is working with no specific settings for hibernate.  My code above probably only helps JDBC code.  You might have a different type of problem.  Can you share some code?

Comment: Also advise on hibernate mapping on this field.

Comment: My POJO class: public class GeneratedLogs implements Serializable {

    private Date systemDate;
    private String userName;
    private String operationName;
    private String status;
    private String message;                                        Have a mysql table 'generatedlog' whose column type is DATETIME to store systemDate   attribute. But mapping error occured while storing data in table.

Comment: Thanks for response. My code is working with this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parse("2014-01-24 11:23:00.000000");
```

I Think this is what you are looking for?

The code is

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
            .parse("2014-01-24 11:23:00.000000");
    System.out.println(temp);
}}
```

Now pass this to your database

Comment: No temp is not a string. Look closely its java.util.Date temp.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hibernate, use a [@Temporal annotation with TemporalType.DATE](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html) and Hibernate should handle things for you. If not, leave a comment.

Comment: I am using hbm.xml files for mapping in hibernate. anything for that?

Comment: Please see http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t115539.html ; but why are you not using annotations?